# How to remove xmlns on language_attributes()?

Tags: plugins, php, filters

Hello I'am getting this error on w3c because `xmlns` is deprecated.

How can I remove `xmlns`?

> Attribute xmlns:fb not allowed here

```
<html lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:addthis="http://www.addthis.com/help/api-spec"  prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

My code is

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
```

```
function get_language_attributes( $doctype = 'html' ) {
    $attributes = array();

    if ( function_exists( 'is_rtl' ) && is_rtl() )
        $attributes[] = 'dir="rtl"';

    if ( $lang = get_bloginfo('language') ) {
        if ( get_option('html_type') == 'text/html' || $doctype == 'html' )
            $attributes[] = "lang=\"$lang\"";

        if ( get_option('html_type') != 'text/html' || $doctype == 'xhtml' )
            $attributes[] = "xml:lang=\"$lang\"";
    }

    $output = implode(' ', $attributes);

    /**
     * Filters the language attributes for display in the html tag.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     * @since 4.3.0 Added the `$doctype` parameter.
     *
     * @param string $output A space-separated list of language attributes.
     * @param string $doctype The type of html document (xhtml|html).
     */
    return apply_filters( 'language_attributes', $output, $doctype );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see by the end of the [`get_language_attributes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_language_attributes/) function there is a call to [`apply_filters`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/). This allows themes and plugins to change the language attributes. In your case the two `xmlns` tags are added, one for facebook and one for addthis.

You will have to check your plugins which ones are doing this. Most likely, you have one that adds a facebook like button and add this sharing buttons. Find a more up to date plugin that uses the `prefix` attribute instead.

Or you could just leave it this way. `xmlns` is deprecated for this type of use, but it's not harmful.